# nopcommerce HTTP, HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, nopcommerce

I'm trying to fetch and show data in nopcommerce store with Reactjs,
for a while I'm stuck on getting the response,

The problem is my Api is still on HTTP, and nopcommerce only accepts from HTTPS.

I tried to disable SSL for nopcommerce but didn't have any luck with it.

Do you have any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Why don't you use HTTPS? That's the obvious answer and something you'll *have* to do no matter what. If the real question is how to test or develop locally when you don't have a valid HTTPS certificate, the solution is to create and trust a self-signed certificate. When you create an ASP.NET Core project for the first time for example, it creates a self-signed dev certificate which allows all ASP.NET Core projects to use HTTPS by default

Comment: I dont have acces to API configuration, and API only takes HTTP requests.
I get your point tho. thanks for the tip !